# A contributed module without an issue tracker on Drupal.org?

Tags: community-official-site

The project page for the [RNG - Events and Registrations](https://www.drupal.org/project/rng) module doesn't seem to have the typical block (column right) with title "Issues for moduleX" (similar to the block for pretty much any other moduleY on Drupal.org). Not sure if there are other modules for which this block is missing also.

Instead its project page does include some links to other sites (though not for "documentation requests" ...), i.e.:

- Bug reports and feature requests.
- Support requests.

What happened to this module's issue queue on Drupal.org?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that within the **edit** section of any project page (which is available to e.g. the project maintainer), inside the <kbd>**Issues**</kbd> tab, there is a checkbox with label **`Enable issue tracker`**.

By default, this checkbox is enabled. But if you disable it, the block (column right) with title "Issues for moduleX" is not shown anymore.

And if you re-enable that checkbox again, the block is also shown again ... And the issues that existed before the block is disabled, seem to still exist. So unchecking that checkbox does not delete all existing issues (as it should be I think).